# Creating conditional script for softwareupdate command

Tags: macos, terminal, script, mdm

Looking to create a script that runs a function if there are software updates available. Currently I am just using this:

```
softwareupdate -ia && myFunction
```

This creates my desired effect, but if there are no software updates available, myFunction should not activate.

Comment: Does softwareupdate even have different exit codes?

Comment: The list command lists updates. Your command triggers the installation. Do you intend to detect availability or an actual installation?

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure about the exit codes. I intend to automatically install all updates and then run myFunction, but if there are no updates available, then don't run myFunction. I tried something like "if softwareupdate is true..." but no success. Perhaps my syntax is wrong

Comment: Well, did you try with the code in your question? What happens if there are no updates?

Comment: Softwareupdate reports back as a success regardless of there are updates or not, causing myFunction to run anyway

Comment: @RyanCoen Then it's not a syntax problem, it's the assumption that the exit status of `softwareupdate` can be used to distinguish whether any updates were performed. You need a different way to distinguish that. Maybe capture the output from `softwareupdate` and examine it? BTW, many (but not all) software updates require a system restart, and the `softwareupdate` command doesn't do that automatically; your script should probably also detect that and do the restart if necessary (probably after running `myFunction`).

Comment: @Gordon ahh you make a good suggestion. I could export the contents of the command to a text file `softwareupdate -ia > output.txt`. Only issue with this is it does not capture the full text. Only captures "Software Update Tool Finding available software". If I could capture "No updates are available", I could work with that. Is there a way to do that?